# Adding 1 hour to time variable

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have a time to which I want to add an hour:

```
$time = '10:09';
```

I've tried:

```
$time = strtotime('+1 hour');

strtotime('+1 hour', $time);

$time = date('H:i', strtotime('+1 hour'));
```

But none of the above work.

Comment: `$time = 10:09;` is not the proper way to define time

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Worked for me..

```
$timestamp = strtotime('10:09') + 60*60;

$time = date('H:i', $timestamp);

echo $time;//11:09
```

---

Explanation:

`strtotime('10:09')` creates a numerical timestamp in seconds, something like `1510450372`. Simply add or remove the amount of seconds you need and use `date()` to convert it back into a human readable format.

```
$timestamp = strtotime('10:09') + 60*60; // 10:09 + 1 hour
$timestamp = strtotime('10:09') + 60*60*2; // 10:09 + 2 hours
$timestamp = strtotime('10:09') - 60*60; // 10:09 - 1 hour
```

`time()` also creates a numerical timestamp but for right now. You can use it in the same way.

```
$timestamp = time() + 60*60; // now + 1 hour
```

Comment: if i have to decress a hour ('10:09') - 60*60; Will Work ??

Comment: @TarangP Yes! `strtotime('10:09')` creates a timestamp in seconds. Simply add or remove the amount of seconds you need

Answer (score 30):

You can do like this

```
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('4 minute'));
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('6 hour'));
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('2 day'));
```

Comment: where do you pass in a time variable? all of these are based on the current time it runs

Answer (score 17):

try this it is worked for me.

```
$time="10:09";
$time = date('H:i', strtotime($time.'+1 hour'));
echo $time;
```

Comment: Surprisingly straight forward thanks!
    $timeFormat = date("d/m/y H:i:s", strtotime($timeFormat .'+8 hours'));

Comment: In my case I want to add 1.30 hours. Giving +1.30 did not worked as expected. Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: @Pravin `$time = date('H:i', strtotime($time.'+1 hour'.'+30 minutes'));`

Answer (score 16):

```
$time = '10:09';
$timestamp = strtotime($time);
$timestamp_one_hour_later = $timestamp + 3600; // 3600 sec. = 1 hour

// Formats the timestamp to HH:MM => outputs 11:09.
echo strftime('%H:%M', $timestamp_one_hour_later);
// As crolpa suggested, you can also do
// echo date('H:i', $timestamp_one_hour_later);
```

Check PHP manual for [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime), [strftime()](http://www.php.net/date) and [date()](http://www.php.net/date) for details.

BTW, in your initial code, you need to add some quotes otherwise you will get PHP syntax errors:

```
$time = 10:09; // wrong syntax
$time = '10:09'; // syntax OK

$time = date(H:i, strtotime('+1 hour')); // wrong syntax
$time = date('H:i', strtotime('+1 hour')); // syntax OK
```

Answer (score 14):

## 2020 Update

It is weird that no one has suggested the OOP way:

```
$date = new \DateTime(); //now
$date->add(new \DateInterval('PT3600S'));//add 3600s / 1 hour
```

OR

```
$date = new \DateTime(); //now
$date->add(new \DateInterval('PT60M'));//add 60 min / 1 hour
```

OR

```
$date = new \DateTime(); //now
$date->add(new \DateInterval('PT1H'));//add 1 hour
```

Extract it in string with format:

```
var_dump($date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this code:

```
$time = '10:09';

echo date( 'H:i', strtotime( '+1 hour' , strtotime($time) ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple and smart solution:

```
date("H:i:s", time()+3600);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$time = strtotime("10:09") + 3600;
echo date('H:i', $time);
```

Or `date_add`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me
use `DateTime::modify` or `date_modify`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php

```php
// Example:

$timestamp = 1680947903;
// Timestamp to datetime
$date = new \DateTime('@'. $timestamp );
$date->modify('+1 hour');
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzdW8.png)

Answer (score -2):

I had a similar problem and the fix was to say “hours” instead of “hour”.

Answer (score -3):

Beware of adding 3600!! may be a problem on day change because of unix timestamp format uses moth before day.

e.g. 2012-03-02 23:33:33 would become 2014-01-13 13:00:00 by adding 3600 better use mktime and date functions they can handle this and things like adding 25 hours etc.

Answer (score -4):

**2021 Update**

Worked for me..

```
$text = str_replace(':PM', '', '19:00:PM');   //19:00:PM  //Removes :PM
$text = str_replace(':AM', '', $text);   //Removes :AM
$time = strtotime($text);   //19:00
$startTime = date("H:i:A", strtotime('- 1 hours', $time));
$endTime = date("H:i:A", strtotime('+ 1 hours', $time));
```

Output:

```
echo $startTime; //18:00:PM
echo $endTime;  //20:00:PM
```