# PHP not adding days in date

Tags: php

PHP:

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('Insert_date'));
$data['Insert_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$data['Credit_limit'] = date($data['Insert_date'], strtotime("+10 days"));
echo $data['Insert_date'].'<br>';
echo $data['Credit_limit'].'<br>';
```

Output:

```
2017-09-01
2017-09-01
```

Expected Output:

```
2017-09-01
2017-09-11
```

Anyone can please help me why $data['Credit_limit'] != 2017-09-11. Why 10 days is not added in $data['Credit_limit'] How can I resolve this issue? please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding 1 hour to time variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8552106/adding-1-hour-to-time-variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format for [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) is wrong:

```
$data['Credit_limit'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['Insert_date'] . " +10 days"));
```

---

**Explanation:**

You need to add the date inside `strtotime` function. [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function holds the format as the first parameter like this: `date($format)` .

Answer (score 0):

You are using date function in wrong way

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', '2017-09-01');
$data['Insert_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$data['Credit_limit'] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+10 days",strtotime($data['Insert_date'])));
echo $data['Insert_date'].'<br>';
echo $data['Credit_limit'].'<br>';
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/WrRbj)

Answer (score 0):

The second date formatting is incorrect. Try to concatenare the date and plus expression

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('Insert_date'));
$data['Insert_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$data['Credit_limit'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . " + 10 days"));
echo $data['Insert_date'].'<br>';
echo $data['Credit_limit'].'<br>';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $this->input->post('Insert_date'));
$data['Insert_date'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
$data['Credit_limit'] = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data['Insert_date'] . " +10 days"));
echo $data['Insert_date'].'<br>';
echo $data['Credit_limit'].'<br>';
```